# How disable dropdown jQuery hover function when resizing screen

Tags: jquery, navbar, jquery-hover

I want to make a user-friendly responsive website, but I am not familiar with jQuery. Hopefully you guys can help me further. When the screen size shrinks (max 767px), I want to disable my dropdown hover function of jQuery. Only thing I want is the click function instead of hover.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu", this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("open");         
    }, function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu", this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');          
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to use jQuery's $(window).resize event to check the $(window).width.  However, there can be additional complexity based upon how different browsers treat scroll bars (see https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries).  Also, with binding and unbinding, the hover event doesn't work.  The hover event is really just a direct implementation of the mouseenter and mouseleave events. The following should work for you, though.  Let me know if there's trouble as I didn't test it.

```
    $(window).resize(function(){    
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {  
             $(".dropdown").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
        else {
            $(".dropdown").bind({
                 mouseenter: function() {
                    $(".dropdown-menu", this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
                    $(this).toggleClass("open");
                 },
                 mouseleave: function() {
                    $(".dropdown-menu", this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
                    $(this).toggleClass('open');
                 }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! When resizing the screen to a maximum of 767px the hover function is disabled just what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please don't forget to mark the answer if your problem is indeed solved.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and simplest way is to use jQuery resize event and check the current window size and decide if we need to bind or unbind our events. Here is a fiddle showing one way of doing it. Keep in mind there are lots of things to handle like checking if the size changed, properly unbinding events and making sure we don't continually rebind the same event. Feel free to ask any questions.

As for the direct title of your question. You don't really disable events but unbind them and to unbind hover you use: `off('mouseenter mouseleave')`. Per jquery docs: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

> To unbind the above example use:
>
> 1 $( "td" ).off( "mouseenter mouseleave" );

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f81tsgtn/4/

JS:

```
// Initialize
var $window = $(window);
var $dropdown = $(".dropdown");
var $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu", $dropdown);
var currentSize = $window.width();
var currentEvent = '';

// Attach current event on load
(currentSize >= 767) ? bindOne('hover') : bindOne('click');

// Atach window resize event
$window.resize(function() {
    // get windows new size
    var newSize = $window.width();

    // Exit if size is same
    if (currentSize == newSize) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if its greater/smaller and which current event is attached so we dont attach multiple events
    if (newSize >= 767 && currentEvent != 'hover') {
        bindOne('hover');
    } else if (newSize < 767 && currentEvent != 'click') {
        bindOne('click');
    }

    // Update new size
    currentSize = newSize;
});

// Handles binding/unbinding of events
function bindOne (eventType) {
    if (eventType == 'hover') {
        // Update currentEvent
        currentEvent = eventType;

        // Make sure all previous events are removed and attach hover
        $dropdown.off('click').off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(
            function() {
                $dropdownMenu.stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
            },
            function() {
                $dropdownMenu.stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
            }
        );
    }
    else if (eventType == 'click') {
        // Update currentEvent
        currentEvent = eventType;

        // Make sure all previous events are removed and attach hover
        $dropdown.off('mouseenter mouseleave').off('click').on('click',
            function() {
                $dropdownMenu.stop(true, true).fadeToggle("fast");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    hello
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        hello again
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have more than one dropdown with submenu, i tried `var $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu", this, $dropdown);` in order to select each one, but of course, it didn't work.  Could you write how to show each dropdown submenu for each dropdown menu?  I'm thinking I must do something like this `$dropdown.each(function(i){});`, but I don't know where to place it. Many thanks.

Comment: @Chris22 give me a day or so. My computer broke. Getting a new one tomorrow and then I can try to reply and help.

Comment: sorry to hear about your computer!  Thank you for your help.  I've been trying a few things, but your code is well commented and reads like a tutorial so I'm learning from it.

Comment: hope you got a great new computer!  Was wondering if you had a chance to show in your code how to show each dropdown submenu for each dropdown menu when you have more than one dropdown with submenus?  Thanks.

Comment: @Chris22 sorry. I'll try to reply tonight or tomorrow when I get home. Been so busy.

Comment: hope all is well with your computer!  just wanted to check to see if you had a chance to add "multiple" dropdown submenu code.  I'm not having much luck. Don't mean to keep bugging you, just can't seem to find this of solution.  Thanks

Comment: @Chris22 Sorry. Been so busy. I need to see your html structure to tell you how to select each submenu. But in theory guessing some classes you can do something like `var $dropdownsubMenus = $(".dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu", $dropdown);`. Then just loop over them.